# How to change the appearance of the Insertion cursor of an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm working on a little project and want to change the appearance of the little blinking bar, which appears infront of a spot you're typing in. Its also known as just a 'cursor' or 'text-cursor'. I can change it either with css or javascript if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do that, you'd have to hide it entirely and provide your own graphic, managing its position, etc.; basically, reinventing the text input field.

The closest you can come with CSS is [`caret-color`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#propdef-caret-color), which lets you set the color in modern browsers but won't work in IE (and is [only supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-caret-color) in **very** recent versions of Edge, the ones based on Blink and V8 instead of EdgeHTML and JScript). My impression is you want to do more than that. :-)

Comment: Yes indeed, my idea was to change it to its appearance in a command line. I'll remake it entirely then. Thanks for the information! One more question, can you hide it at all?

Comment: @coder - I think if the `input` is visible, you'll struggle to hide the insertion point cross-browser. On browsers that support `caret-color` it'll be easy enough: Make it the color of the input's background. But for ones that don't... :-)

Comment: So the easy solution would be to can internet explorer, I see :)

Comment: @coder - :-) Well, Edge didn't get it until v76 (e.g.: **just now** or arguably next month), so...